# Deploying an Intra Business App for Ipad, Details?

Tags: ipad

Recently I have been tasked with creating an application for a business that basically deals with strange and volatile inventory requirements .  I know there are many more robust alternatives but they rather have their hearts set on deploying the field portion of the application using iPad's.  I dabbled with cocoa and Objective-C apps in the past, I even wrote a couple of useless apps.  I do not think the client side application will be that complicated. However, I'm wondering how I would deploy an update the application on the iPad.  Does apple have a service for this or do I have to jail break them ?  I looked on Apple's website, however did not find very much information regarding client specific application.

Does anyone have any experience with this ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the [`iOS Developer Enterprise Program`](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/) for developing in-house apps.

Comment: Cool, you know  how much does a DUNS number cost  ?? ... I was looking in the wrong place I guess.

Comment: Frankly, I have no experience with the enterprise program. I just know it applies to your use case. And after a few minutes of online search,  DUNS number seems to be [`free`](http://www.dnb.com/about-dnb/14950284-1.html#J2).